# Report Builder 3.0 (SSRS) - Highlight Row in Matrix Based on Max Value in Column Group

Tags: matrix, expression, grouping, conditional-formatting, reportbuilder3.0

I have been tasked with writing a report with a matrix that categorizes and groups data by rows and columns, and I'm told that each row must be a certain color based on which column group the maximum count appears in.

So I created my matrix. On the rows, it is grouped first by state and then by city, and it has a total row at the bottom. The column group is based on two calculated fields I created. Here are their labels and expressions:

DaysSinceLastUpdate

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Fields!RECORD_UPDATED_DATE.Value,Today())
```

DaysSinceUpdateGrouping

```
=Switch(Fields!DaysSinceLastUpdate.Value<91,"Less Than 90 Days", Fields!DaysSinceLastUpdate.Value<181,"91-180 Days", Fields!DaysSinceLastUpdate.Value<365,"181-365 Days", Fields!DaysSinceLastUpdate.Value>=365,"More Than 1 Year")
```

So my table looks like this:

| State | City | DaysSinceUpdateGrouping | Total Records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | City | CountDistinct(RecordID) | CountDistinct(RecordID) |
| State | Total | CountDistinct(RecordID) | CountDistinct(RecordID) |
| Total |  | CountDistinct(RecordID) | CountDistinct(RecordID) |

When the report runs, a user selects one or more states using a parameter. If a user picked just Oregon, the results might look something like this:

| State | City | Less Than 90 Days | 91-180 Days | 181-365 Days | More Than 1 Year | Total Records |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Portland | 50 | 80 | 100 | 10 | 240 |
|  | Eugene | 40 | 20 | 60 | 100 | 220 |
|  | Bend | 100 | 10 | 0 | 20 | 130 |
| Oregon | Total | 190 | 110 | 160 | 130 | 590 |
| Total |  | 190 | 110 | 160 | 130 | 590 |

What I want to do is make each entire row change color based on where the maximum value appears. For Portland, the highest value is in the "181-365" days column, so I want that row orange. For Eugene, the highest value is in the "More Than 1 Year" column, so I want that row red. For Bend, the highest value is in the "Less Than 90 Days" column, so I want that row green. Both the Oregon and Total rows should also be green. (If the "91-180 Days" column had the maximum value, its associated row should be yellow.)

I selected the cells I wanted to apply the background color rule to, and I applied this expression for the Fill property:

```
=switch(max(Fields!DaysSinceUpdateGrouping.Value, "City")="Less Than 90 Days","LimeGreen", max(Fields!DaysSinceUpdateGrouping.Value, "City")="91-180 Days","Yellow",   max(Fields!DaysSinceUpdateGrouping.Value, "City")="181-365 Days","Orange", max(Fields!DaysSinceUpdateGrouping.Value, "City")="More Than 1 Year","Tomato")
```

But the row always turns red.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How can I tell the Fill expression to find the maximum value in the column group for each row?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I had to add a row group for DaysSinceUpdateGrouping in addition to the column group. Then I deleted the column that appeared but left the group in place. That way, in my Switch expression for the cell color, I was able to replace "City" with "DaysSinceUpdateGrouping1" so that the reference was calculating the details, not the City total.

Comment: Never mind. I thought I had it. Adding a row group did allow me to get my conditional formatting right, but it created four rows per City where, in each row, one column showed an actual value and the other three showed 0. So, I still need help with this if anybody has any ideas...